# Moving an object by its vertices to another objects vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, transforms

so I'm quite new to blender and may have missed something glaringly obvious. What I am trying to do is move a mesh to another mesh so it overlaps let's call them Mesh A and Mesh B. The meshes itself has quite a lot of vertices. I need these two meshes to align exactly so my thinking is to select one of the vertices of mesh A and move the whole mesh by that specific vertice onto another specific vertice on Mesh B. Here is where I am stuck. I cant seem to select individual verticies in Object mode and precisely guide it to another vertice. I tried Vertice snapping but it seems to only want to snap the "edge" vertice instead of the one i am trying to use. In Edit mode, moving verticies only move the vertice and not the whole object so thats not what i want either. I feel like its such a simple task esp as i'm used to other 3D modelling software like Rhino so this simple task not working makes me think i am missing something. I have attached some images below to try illustrate what i would like. Appreciate any advice and help on this! :)

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Ok so halfway through typing this i figured out you had to move the pivot point of the mesh to the vertice you want to use and go from there.... Quite a bit of effort just to move one vertice to another please tell me there is another method...

Comment: yes you can put the origin on the vertex you want on one of your objects, then put the 3D cursor on the same vertex on the other object, select the first object and Shift S > Selection to Cursor

Comment: (That's the _Selection to Cursor_ with the 'Keep Offset' option)

Answer (score 2):

as moonboots said, it can be easily done, but i am not sure whether his explanation is "enough" for beginners, so here the short story long:

Let's say you got a plane and a cone and you want to move one vertex of the plane to the top of the cone:

[image]

1.) select your plane

2. tab for edit mode
3. select your vertex

[image]

4. Shift - S -> Cursor to selected

[image]

5. Tab
6. Object -> Origin to cursor

[image]

7. select the cone
8. tab for edit mode
9. select your vertex
10. Shift S -> Cursor to selected

[image]

11. tab
12. select your plane
13. Shift - S -> Selection to cursor

[image]

14. result:

[image]